# Accessing BPM and time signature of Plug-In Host

Tags: audiounit, vst

I am working on an audio plugin and would like to map LFOs to various parameters. How does the plug-in access the DAW's BPM value and time signature?

Does the host need to expose this through VST or AU protocols or how should a plug-in access properties it needs during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone with the same requirement, the JUCE library has an object called [AudioPlayHead](https://www.juce.com/doc/classAudioPlayHead)

You can then get the current position info inside your processing callback

```
audioPlayHead->getCurrentPosition(currentPositionInfo)
```

and then access the BPM on the position info using `currentPositionInfo.bpm`